# using data.table to generate new column from existing columns

Tags: r, data.table

The data looks like:

```
V1 <- rnorm(10,10,1)
V2 <- rnorm(10,30,2)
V3 <- rnorm(10,100,20)
V4 <- rnorm(10,50,2)

df <- as.data.table(cbind(V1,V2,V3,V4))
```

I want to generate a new variable (e.g., `V5`) which is the sum of other three existing variables (e.g., `V1`,`V2` and `V3`). Below is my solution:

```
col2sum <- paste0("V",seq(1,3),collapse = " + ")
df <- df[, V5 := col2sum)]
```

The above is a minimal example of my question. Please note that my actual situation is more complicated. I just need to make the expression more efficient. Why my solution doesn't work? I believe `col2sum` gives the correct expression to calculate V5. Please correct me. Many thanks!

Comment: As an aside, get out of the habit of doing `data.table(cbind(...` - just `data.table(V1,V2,V3,V4)` is enough and will avoid unintended outcomes like making all numbers text.

Comment: @thelatemail Oh, Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: You are assigning the text `"V1 + V2 + V3"` to `V5` - no different to doing `df[, V5 := "some text"]`

Comment: Your "solution" does not yet work, so efficiency is the least of your concerns, right?

Comment: @thelatemail You are right, I am so stupid! Is it possible to transfer the results from 'paste()' to be an expression? or I need to think of doing this in another way? Any hints?

Comment: `df[, V5 := Reduce(\`+\`, .SD), .SDcols=c("V1","V2","V3")]` maybe?

Comment: @Frank Yeah, that is definitely not a "solution". I just wondering if I could pass the results of 'past()' or 'grep()' to be used as an expressions?

Comment: @thelatemail The code in your last comment works. Hmm, interesting, I didn't use the `Reduce` function that often. Good to know. Thank you!

Comment: @thelatemail One thing I want to point out is that your solution still need to type all of those used columns out. I would like to see something like '.SDcols = col2sum' can work. My actual data set is really tedious with the variable names, I can't type them out one by one. Thanks for your help though

Comment: @ChuanTang - there's no reason you can't pass `paste0("V", 1:3)` to `.SDCols=`

Comment: @thelatemail You're right. I think my problem has been solved, you can add it as an answer if you want and I will up vote it. Thank you!

Comment: Regarding tedious names, you can put your data in long format assuming it's all numeric (or the same class, anyways), like `mdf = melt(df[, r := .I], id = "r")`. From there, normal data.table syntax applies `mdf[, sum(value), by=r]` and so on. Computations across columns should be rare...

Comment: @ChuanTang - I think Frank has the actual pro-tip there - dealing with V1:Vn columns is always a bit of a mess.

Comment: @Frank Great! Thank you!

Comment: if you have expressions in string format, you can try `df[, V5 := eval(parse(text = col2sum))]`. It's tedious but works.